# Where do I go to add a tag before the closing body tag?

Tags: code

I need to disable Rich Pins for one post and was told to "add this tag to the header of your page before the closing body tag.

"

Where specifically do I access that to add the tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you are trying to add and provide a link to who/what/where is telling you to do this so we can give you an accurate answer. Also you say "header" but closing body tag is technically where your "footer" is.

Comment: Here's the content of the directions I was given by Pinterest:                         If you want to remove Rich Pin data from a content page, simply add this tag to the header of your page before the closing body tag:
<meta name="pinterest-rich-pin" content="false" />
The tag will override the Rich Pin meta tags on that page only and not affect the rest of your site. If you ever want to turn Rich Pins back on, remove the tag and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to put this in your header within your `<head>` tags before your opening `<body>` tag.

Put the following into your theme's `function.php` file:

```
function wpse_285611_pinterest_rich_pins() {
    //change 123 to the ID of the post OR
    //change 123 to the slug or title of the post
    if ( is_single(123) ) {
        echo '<meta name="pinterest-rich-pin" content="false" />';
    }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'wpse_285611_pinterest_rich_pins', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/ for information on how to use the `is_single` conditional template tag if you want to restrict this to one post only.